# VBA dynamic array subscript error

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to take some values from an excel sheet, to then process them, and I decided to use a Dynamic array, because I thought that it would be easier.

```
Dim Dias() As Variant
Dim Horas() As Variant
Dim Temp() As Variant
Dim Hum() As Variant

Sheets("Tfinal").Activate
Dias = Range("A2:A1745")
Horas = Range("B2:B1745")
Temp = Range("J2:J1745")

Sheets("Hfinal").Activate
Hum = Range("D2:D1745")

Dim TempNTemp() As Double
Dim NTemp() As Double
Dim NDias() As Variant
Dim NHoras() As Variant
Dim TempNHum() As Variant
Dim NHum() As Variant
```

Until here everything's fine, but the next line throws subscript out of range error. I'm really confused.

```
H = Horas(0)
```

Comment: Getting values from a range of cells **always** results in a 2-D array with a 1-based index.

Answer (score 3):

Getting values from a range of cells **always** results in a 2-D array with a 1-based index. If you use a number of cells in a single column you still get a 1 to x, 1 to 1 array; if you use a number of cells in a single row you will get a 1 to 1, 1 to x array.

Your arrays are LBound/UBound/Ranked as follows:

```
Dias = Range("A2:A1745")    1 to 1744, 1 to 1
Horas = Range("B2:B1745")   1 to 1744, 1 to 1
Temp = Range("J2:J1745")    1 to 1744, 1 to 1
Hum = Range("D2:D1745")     1 to 1744, 1 to 1
```

So to access the first element of the first rank Horas array use one of the following:

```
Horas(1, 1)
Horas(LBound(Horas, 1), 1)
```

Truth be told, the default for the second rank is 1 so it is unnecessary. These will work just as well.

```
Horas(1)
Horas(LBound(Horas))
```

However, using that shorthand can cause confusion if you had more than a single second rank.

```
Horus = Range("A1:G1")
'first element
Horas(1, 1)
Horas(1, LBound(Horas, 2))
'second element
Horas(1, 2)
```

Setting a **Watch** on the array var will show you the dimensions as well as the contents.

I also use the following code within the procedure to visually see the array's dimensions in the Immediate window.

```
debug.print lbound(Horus, 1) & ":" & ubound(Horus, 1)
debug.print lbound(Horus, 2) & ":" & ubound(Horus, 2)
'results for Horus
1:1744
1:1
```